# Load local image in processing for Android sketch

Tags: android, processing

I have a **Processing 3** sketch which is working fine in *Java* mode. It loads images:

```
void setup() {
  bkImg = loadImage("my_img.jpg");
}
```

`my_img.jpg` is stored locally in the processing project folder.

When running it in *Android* Mode on an Android device it fails:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /data/user/0/processing.test.basic_android_test/files/my_img.jpg (No such
>   file or directory)

What am I doing wrong? Where should I store the image? Any hint?

No clues on [Processing 3 reference](https://processing.org/reference/loadImage_.html). :(

Comment: That error message tells you where the sketch is looking. It is looking in `/data/user/0/processing.test.basic_android_test/files`. Is your file `my_img.jpg` in that directory?

Comment: mmm... @JohnColeman: Processing sketches are supposed to be self-contained. My images files are in the root project directory. And processing-for-android should take care of deploying where-ever they are supposed to be. (Or at least, this is what I think. Same as it does with Processing-for-Java)

Comment: [this](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/how-to-correctly-store-app-specific-files-in-android/) suggests that Android has its own way of doing things, to which Processing for Android would need to conform. It would be nice if the documentation discussed it. Perhaps you can create a data directory in your root project directory, store the images there, and be a little more informative about the location of the file in the `loadImage()` call. It is a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your quote: "No clues on Processing 3 reference. :("

according to the doc:

"images must be located **in the data directory** of the current sketch."

So you should put your images in the data directory of your sketch.

Hope this helps.

Peace.

Comment: Great! My mistake interpreting the doc. Image must be stored in data directory (literally named 'data'!): `my_project_folder/data/my_img.jpg` ...not necessary for running the sketch in 'Java mode', though.